# C++ and SOAP -> how to start well

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

My project is about to introduce SOAP. It's going to be used for C++ <-> Java and C++ <-> Flex communication. I'm responsible for refactoring our apps to take advantage of Java business rules engine and new Flex gui.

What resources are must read for C++ SOAP? I've read W3 materials. We're probably be using gSOAP on Solaris boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some reasonably good books on SOAP, like [Programming Web Services with SOAP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596000952) by Snell, Tidwell, and Kulchenko; I've given that to people to introduce them to SOAP on projects in the past.  I don't know of a C++-specific book, but the gSOAP site has pretty decent documentation.

I think the really key thing is probably to not dive into a complicated project right at first; there are some SOAP tutorials around, like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/eBaygSOAP.aspx), that build simple web services using gSOAP.  Get the SOAP version of "Hello, world!" going firt, then maybe build that eBay client in the example, and you'll learn a lot of things you'd learn much more slowly and painfully trying to build a big example first.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to not use SOAP. Have you considered something like Protocol Buffers or Thrift?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/cpptutorial.html and http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/